# Why doesn't this simple while loop work with sympy?

Tags: python, while-loop, sympy

Consider the following commands

```py
from sympy import init_session()
init_session

def test(v, th):
    va = v
    val = 5*ln((2*(10**4))/(2*(10**4)+va-10))
    while (va-val > th):
        va=va-0.01
        val = 5*ln((2*10**4)/(2*10**4+va-10))
    return val
```

Mathematically, we have the equation

`va=5*ln((2*(10**4))/(2*(10**4)+va-10))`

and we are trying, in a very rudimentary way, to find `va` iteratively.

I am not worried about the math. I don't understand, however, why the above code does not run.

[image]

In `.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/testing/runtests.py", line 545, in _test`

[image]

and in `.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/testing/runtests.py", line 134, in convert_to_native_paths`

[image]

Comment: The first two lines of your snippet are wrong.  Was that a cut-and-paste error?

Comment: Please post code, data, **and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Your stack trace contains images and is illegible. Please paste the full trace into the question as text, using triple backticks.

Comment: The problem is that `init_session()` creates an interactive session immediately, so YOUR `test` function is never seen.  It's running one of its own.  Make the first line `from sympy import *`, delete the `init_session()` call, and your code runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a usage problem:

```
from sympy import *

def test(v, th):
    va = v
    val = 5*ln((2*(10**4))/(2*(10**4)+va-10))
    while (va-val > th):
        va=va-0.01
        val = 5*ln((2*10**4)/(2*10**4+va-10))
    return val

print(test(15,1))
```

Output:

```
0.00225050640192679
```